# Using laravel on existing website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I am currently an intern for a company that has a database that is hosted on the company's network. For the past 2 weeks, I have been updating the database with new features and forms through just editing the PHP files they have on the network in notepad++ and uploading them through FileZilla. I was told by users on this site that I should try laravel to clean up the code and to give my code a sense of order. After downloading laravel and figuring out all the configurations, I'm confused on how to apply laravel for my uses. How can I create new PHP files(new page to the database) that will be hosted on my company's network through laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to run before you walk. Before using Laravel, you should learn about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Also, be sure to take a look at this question on [StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, reading over what MVC is was quite interesting and informative. The company already has all of its pages/php files set up in a certain format(everthing in one php file) so it would be difficult to start changing them to MVC formatting. However, maybe I will attempt to make future pages in this format to learn the best PHP practices.